# Is there any automated way that will list all dependencies in sql server stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There are nearly 1449 stored procedures in our database.

Is there any automated way that will list all dependencies?

Like if we have stored procedure s1,s2,s3,s4,s5

- s2,s3 is called in s1
- s4 is called in s2
- s5 is called in s3

so dependency should look somewhat like

```
s1 
-->s2
---->s4
-->s3
---->s5
```

Comment: Rough outline: What I did was determined how the UI does it (Profiler), then looped over all objects into a table with a level indicator....BTW, that seems like a lot of stored procs...

Comment: I don't think there is any automated way that fullfill your requirement

Comment: [Mitch Wheat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) I recently joined this organization. For small things they have separate procedures. I am trying to figure out a way to minimize this. That’s why I needed automated procedure which will show me all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can add all your SP names in a temporary table from,

```
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures
```

Now you can loop through this temporary table and find the dependencies like,

```
DECLARE @Search varchar(255)
SET @Search='PROCEDURE_NAME'
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%'+@Search+'%'
 ORDER BY 2,1
```

I don't know whether it would work or not, but you can give it a try at least.